# How to mock Newtonsoft.Json library and methods JObject.Parse() in C# Xunit

Tags: c#, mocking, xunit, .net-6.0

I am trying to mock Jobject.parse() . I am not able to do it using Moq framework.

```
MethodForUnitTest()
{
//Some Code
var obj = Jobject.Parse("someJsonString");
//SOme code
}
```

How to write a unit test for this method. I want mock this JObject.parse()
How to do this in .net6 web api project

Comment: In general you can't mock static methods you can shim/stub them.

Comment: @GuruStron How can we do shim/stub in .net 6 web api solution

Comment: Check out the question in the duplicate plaque and links in answers. But in general I would say that in most cases when you discover need to shim/stub you need to refactor/redesign your system.